# What does the $, % symbol represent in terms of directories?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

1) I know if you type `%TEMP%` into run, it will open that folder. But what does `%` mean/do?

2) Also, when I'm at work and I type in `\\computername\c$` into windows explorer , it will go to the specified computers `C:\` . I am unsure what `$` means in this situation.

Sorry if this is the wrong place.

Comment: `%Temp%` is a system variable.  `C$` is simply file system variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand slightly on Ramhound's explanation:

**`%TEMP%` is a system variable**, also called **environment variable** or envvar, and it can have any content that you set on it. To check the 'currently' set variables, open a command prompt, and type `set` and it will show the variables that are currently in use, and what they expand to, if you use them with the `%VARIABLE%`.

Some generic examples:

```
PUBLIC=X:\Users\Public
SystemDrive=X:
SystemRoot=X:\WINDOWS
ProgramFiles=X:\Program Files
```

These system variables are useful for programmers who need to install their software to certain locations. Rather than trying to install to C:\ (which as above example does not exist), they can simply invoke `Install to %ProgramFiles%` which will automatically pick the correct path and install at the correct location.

The **`C$` refers to a shared folder** that is set by Windows as a default share. To check for other 'default' share that Windows have --> Computer Management --> Shared Folders. And also, **any share folder with $ at the end are hidden share** and does not appear on share folder listing.

So for example you have some shared folders (in \\computername):

```
myShare
myhiddenShare$
```

Then if someone (or you from other machine) open Windows Explorer and open `\\computername` it will shows that `\\computername\myShare` is shown on the list while myhiddenShare$ is not there.

You can still access `myhiddenShare$` if you know the exact path. So if you enter `\\computername\myhiddenShare$` then you will see the content of the share, it will simply not visible under folder/share listing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The **`%`** directories are `Environment Variables`. i.e. they are already defined in the OS. 
You can learn more about them [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)
You can view your PCs `Environment Variables` like this in Windows 7

- Right Click `My Computer`
- select `Properties`
- Choose `Advanced System Settings`
- goto `Advanced` tab and click on `Environment Variables` Button.
  [image: System Properties]
  It will show you list of  User & System Variables in your system.

Not quite sure about the `c$` but I hope it helps you. :)

Comment: Very good. One way to see them.

Comment: If it helps: `C$` isn't a variable at all.  This isn't BASIC/COMAL.  It's just a name with a marker character that makes it "special".